# How do I find the recurrence equation of T(n) = T(n-1)+n+2?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

Okay so I am supposed to find the recurrence equation of T(n) = T(n-1)+n+2, where T(1) = 1. I know the answer should come out to be 1/2(n(n+5)-4) but I don't understand how to get that answer. I don't need it to be in any computer language, this is just a discrete mathmatics question.

Comment: You may wanna post this question at [math stack](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know expression, you can prove it's correctness with [mathematical induction principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)

claimed:

```
T(n) = 1/2 * n^2 + 5/2 * n - 2
```

check for some n value

```
T(1) = 1/2 + 5/2 - 2 = 1  =>  TRUE
```

then check that formula works when you go from T(n) to T(n+1)

```
T(n+1) = 1/2 * (n+1)^2 + 5/2 * (n+1) - 2 = 
         1/2 * n^2 + n + 1/2 + 5/2 * n + 5/2 - 2 = 
         1/2 * n^2 + 5/2 * n -  2 + n + 1/2 + 5/2 = 
         (1/2 * n^2 + 5/2 * n -  2) + (n + 1) + 2 = 
         T(n) + (n+1) + 2   => TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

With standard sums you get

```
T(n) = T(1) + sum(k=2 to n) (k+2)
     = 1 +sum(k=1 to n) k - 1 + 2*(n-1)
     = n*(n+1)/2 + 2*(n-1)
```

which now can be combined in different fashions.